# Why does '³' (superscript 3) match the python re for alpha characters?

Tags: python, unicode, python-re

This is the match string I use for matching a sequence of Unicode letters - "[^\W\d_]+"

but when I do :

```
import re
re.match("[^\W\d_]+",'³')
```

I get

<re.Match object; span=(0, 1), match='³'>

Why?

Comment: What makes you think that's a regex for letters?

Comment: Not directly related, but worth mentioning: `'³'.isnumeric()` is true.

Answer (score 3):

I think `[^\W\d_]+` matches alphanumeric characters other than digits and underscore:

- `\W` Matches any character which is not a word character. This is the opposite of \w. If the ASCII flag is used this becomes the equivalent of [^a-zA-Z0-9_]. If the LOCALE flag is used, matches characters which are neither alphanumeric in the current locale nor the underscore. (from Python's [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) docs).
- `\d` matches decimal digits
- `_` matches underscore
- `[^blablabla]` matches anything but blablbla
- `[^\W\d_]` matches anything but `\W`, `\d` and `_`. Which means it matches anything but **any character which is not a word character**, **decimal digits**, and **underscore**. Which means it matches word character except decimal digits and underscore. '³' is a word character, and not decimal digit, and not underscore, so it matches.

Comment: `\d` not only matches [0-9] but also other digits, unless the ASCII flag is set

Comment: `[^blablabla]` means any character other than `b`, `l` and `a`.

Comment: Ah yes, when I said blablabla, I meant anything follow the ^ character.

Comment: To expand, /w matches letters, numbers, and underscore. /d matches decimal numbers but there are two other number categories in Unicode which do not match /d but match /w: “Letter Number” e.g. ᛮ (Runic Arlaug Symbol) and “Other Number” e.g. ৵ (Bengali Currency Numerator Two) or ³.  This means that there is no simple way to use Python re to match only Unicode letters.

Comment: If you check the Unicode General Category for SUPERSCRIPT THREE (e.g. using unicodedata.category) you will see that it is No for "Number,other" not Nd for "Number, decimal digit". That is why it gets matched by your regex. If you want more precise control then checking each character for category (Lu, Ll, Lt, Lo) might be your best bet.

Comment: The `\w` and `\W` metacharacters are quite problematic. Python docs define `\w` as matching Unicode word characters. This is technically incorrect. The re module does not use the Unicode definition of `\w` and excludes many word forming characters that has wide impact on African, Central Asian, South East Asian, and South Asian languages. It also negatively impacts most European languages when it is normalised to NFD.